Как переопределить метод плагина Wordpress?
Мне надо переопределить метод get_product_price() из класса wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/includes/modules/woocommerce/class-wc-vars.php. Я почитал, как я понял хука нет для изменения этого метода. Порыскал, что можно через создание дочернего класса, но почему-то тоже не вышло. Путь до файла указал правильный.
В functions.php прописал такой код:
require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/includes/modules/woocommerce/class-wc-vars.php' );
class WC_Vars_New extends WC_Vars
{
    public function get_product_price()
    {
        $product = $this->get_product();
        if (!is_object($product)) {
            return '';
        }

        // if (method_exists($product, 'get_price')) {
        //     $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        //     $filter_prices = array_filter(array_unique(array_column($variations, 'display_price')));
        //     $price = min($filter_prices);
        //     return wp_strip_all_tags(wc_price($price), true);
            return 'по цене от '.wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price( $product->get_price() ), true );

        // }

        return '';
    }
}

Но получаю лишь ошибку, что класс WC_Vars не найден, хотя путь указал верный.

Вы это делаете чтобы втиснуть туда строку "по цене от"?) По идее Вы можете переопределить wc_price, который находится в методе WC_Vars::register() класса который Вы пытаетесь наследовать используя хук rank_math/vars/register_extra_replacements. "Путь до файла указал правильный" -- ну так там еще и namespace есть)

Нет, не обращайте внимание на закомменченное, там логика, чтобы из вариации товаров получить наименьшее, кроме нуля. Поэтому и понадобилось, ибо в тайтл выводится цена товаров, которых нет в наличии. Попробую этот хук, похожее на то, что нужно. Так в итоге, как это через дочерний класс всё провернуть, только создавая свой плагин?

Это незачем проворачивать через дочерний класс

@Simon , попробовал хук, получаю варнинг, что переменная уже зарегестрирована.

Тогда наверное стоит обратиться на их support forum, возможно там есть какой-то неочевидный вариант как сделать ее unregister, либо другой способ реализовать то что Вам нужно. Вы конечно можете по прежнему попробовать с наследованием. После Вашего require_once() добавьте use RankMath\WooCommerce\WC_Vars;, но вероятнее всего, это Вам не поможет.
